# Functional: construct a list of integers 1..n

Tags: functional-programming, recursion, scheme, sml

This is not homework. I'm learning Standard ML on my own. I know a bit of Scheme, too, so this question ought to be answerable in either language.

My self-imposed assignment is to write a function that constructs a list of integers from 1 to n. For example, list(7) should return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. An O(n) solution would be ideal.

It's easy to construct a list in reverse (i.e., [n,n-1,..,1]) in linear time:

```
fun list 1 = 1::nil
|   list n = n::list(n-1);
```

My attempt to construct a list going forward is O(n^2) because the append operation is linear.

```
fun list 1 = 1::nil
|   list n = list(n-1) @ n::nil;
```

My next attempt was to build a list from the end to the front (right to left) by starting with the nil, attaching n to the front, and recursing backwards to 1. But it didn't work at all.

```
fun list n = (if n = 1
              then 1
              else list(n-1) :: n) :: nil;
```

Something makes me think I need a helper function that builds un-terminated lists to be used in the recursion, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using the [Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/),

```
fun list n = List.tabulate (n, fn x => x + 1)
```

#### With a simple accumulator,

```
val list =
    let fun list' k 0 = k
          | list' k n = list' (n::k) (n-1)
    in list' nil end
```

This builds a list starting from the tail end.  If you think of the reductions,

```
   list 5
=> list' nil 5
=> list' (5::nil) 4
=> list' (4::5::nil) 3
=> list' (3::4::5::nil) 2
=> list' (2::3::4::5::nil) 1
=> list' (1::2::3::4::5::nil) 0
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

#### Alternatively,

> Something makes me think I need a helper function that builds un-terminated lists to be used in the recursion, but I'm stumped.

A representation of an unterminated list is a function which takes a list and returns a list: for example, to represent `10::_`, you could use `fn x => 10::x`.

```
fun list n =
    let fun list' m k = if m > n then k nil else
                        list' (m+1) (fn x => k (m::x))
    in list' 1 (fn x => x) end
```

Once again, if you think of the reductions,

```
   list 5
=> list' 1 (fn x => x)
=> list' 2 (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x))
=> list' 3 (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x))
=> list' 4 (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x))
=> list' 5 (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x)) (4::x))
=> list' 6 (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x)) (4::x)) (5::x))
=> (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x)) (4::x)) (5::x)) nil
=> (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x)) (4::x)) (5::nil)
=> (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::x)) (4::5::nil)
=> (fn x => (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::x)) (3::4::5::nil)
=> (fn x => (fn x => x) (1::x)) (2::3::4::5::nil)
=> (fn x => x) (1::2::3::4::5::nil)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In this case, the algorithm can be structured such that an ordinary data structure suffices for the accumulator, but using a continuation as an accumulator is a very powerful and useful technique that should not be overlooked.

Comment: You'll notice that both methods here are tail-recursive.  That's another thing that accumulators are useful for.  Think about how an optimizing compiler might use an accumulator to make non-tail-recursive functions into tail-recursive functions, and see if you can structure your algorithms to lend themselves towards this goal.

Answer (score 3):

One classic approach is to build it in reverse order, then reverse it. That's two times O(n), which is of course just as O(n).

Comment: Had to look up how to do a linear-time reverse. Once I got that to work, the rest was easy.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
fun list n =
  let
    fun f 1 m = m::nil
    |   f n m = m::f (n-1) (m+1)
  in
    f n 1
  end;
```

Comment: I think you meant m::f (n-1) (m+1) instead of m::list (n-1) (m+1)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I cringe whenever I see a non-tail-recursive function that can be easily rewritten to be tail-recursive.

Comment: I just wanted to show the most obvious solution based on what Barry already had. I suppose I should've noted that a tail recursive solution is possible, but Chris Conway already did that.

Comment: It's only a tiny cringe ;)  If this weren't for educational purposes, I would suggest `fun list n = List.tabulate (n, fn x => x + 1)` as the best implementation.  Actually, maybe I'll still do that...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version using a helper function and a tail-recursion-enabling accumulator:

```
fun list n =
  let
    fun aux i acc = 
      if i > 0
      then aux (i-1) (i::acc)
      else acc
  in
    aux n nil
  end;
```

Comment: Wont that be the result in reverse?

Comment: This is nearly identical to my first answer, although I flipped the argument order of the helper so that partial evaluation worked out nicely.  If I had realized that earlier, I probably wouldn't have written mine :)

Answer (score 2):

With list problems like these, it is often easier to solve a more general problem.

> How do I build a list containing the integers *i* such that *n <= i <= m*, in order?

The solution has a base case and an induction step:

- If *n > m*, the list is empty.
- If *n <= m*, the solution is to write *n* followed by the solution to the problem *n+1 <= i <= m*.

This view leads quickly to clear, concise ML code (tested):

```
fun range n m = if n > m then [] else n :: range (n+1) m
fun list n = range 1 n
```

Comment: That's exactly where I was going with this problem. I figured if I could get it to work for 1..n, I could eventually get it working for m..n. As it is, with ephemient's help, I've created a function that creates a list from the first, second, and last element, similar to one of the ways Haskell allows users to construct lists.

Comment: You could even take advantage of partial evaluation and write `val list = range 1` :)

Comment: @ephemient: Sweet.  (But I think you mean partial *application*.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (iota n)
  (let f ((i n)(a '())
    (if (zero? i)
        (reverse a)
        (f (- i 1) (cons i a)))))
```

Comment: Using SRFI-1's unfold-right: (define (iota n) (unfold-right zero? 1- 1- n)) (where 1- is defined the usual way: (define (1- x) (- x 1)))

Comment: Build in reverse order then reverse: (define (iota n) (reverse (unfold zero? 1- 1- n)))